# Settings API and 'type' => 'font'

Tags: options, settings-api, fonts

```
array(
    'name'        => 'textarea',
    'label'       => __( 'Textarea Input', 'wedevs' ),
    'desc'        => __( 'Textarea description', 'wedevs' ),
    'placeholder' => __( 'Textarea placeholder', 'wedevs' ),
    'type'        => 'textarea'
),
```

Just like in the above example the `'type' => 'textarea'`

what is its equivalent for a font?

I tried →

`'type' => 'font'`; but that didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no field in HTML called font. You need to create select dropdown. Also change it's name for uniqueness.